# Supporting mulitple versions of Firefox (2.*, 3.*). What should I test?

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, firefox3.6, firefox2

I have a situation in which I did web development (Wicket running on Tomcat) on Firefox 3.6.3, and now need to support Firefox 2.0 as well. Do you have any tips on what I should expect to break or where I should focus my testing?

Comment: Are you building a webpage or a plugin ?

Comment: @Michael: webpage.  I clarified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few discrepancies to test between Firefox 2 and later versions:

- Use `white-space: -moz-pre-wrap` for Firefox 2 to emulate `white-space: pre-wrap` in Firefox 3+
- Text in Firefox 2 Mac with opacity set has reduced contrast
- Use `display:-moz-inline-box` in a separate declaration to trigger the Firefox 2 experimental layout which approximates `display:inline-block` for a particular element.
- Add a fixed width div nested in the wrapper to address the limitations of `-moz-inline-box` in Firefox 2.